# Passing values to another php page using anchor tag

Tags: php, anchor

I try to pass value of PersonID from list.php to Delete.php.
using anchor tag

Here is my code :

```
<A HREF = "Delete.php?PID = <?php echo $row['PersonID']; ?>"> Delete </A>
```

The value is passed correctly but somehow I don't get redirected to Delete.php can anyone note the problem in the above line?

Comment: Does it direct you anywhere, if so, where?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get rid of the space in your URL:

```
<a href="Delete.php?PID=<?php echo $row['PersonID']; ?>"> Delete </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the spaces before and after the '=':

```
<A HREF="Delete.php?PID=<?php echo $row['PersonID']; ?>"> Delete </A>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this:

```
<a href="Delete.php?PID=<?php echo $row['PersonID']; ?>">Delete</a>
```

No more problem in the line. You should check other code.

Answer (score 0):

Code is very well written. I don't know about your database fields and your php file naming conventions but this might help you.

```
<a href="Delete.php?PID=<?=$row['PersonID']?>">Delete</a>
```

It is same as above but might be it'll helpful.
Check your file name delete.php as same in your directory.
check your database field name. Is it same you are using ?