# Reacting differently to links leading to the same page with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two html pages, linking to each other with  tags. However, the behavior of the opened page needs to be different, based on which link is clicked to get there.
Example: One of the links is in a drop down header menu, and the new window should start with this menu open and then retract it.
The other link is in a blurb on the front page, and the opened page should therefore not start with the header dropdown opened and then retract it.

Is there a way to modify behaviour of the opened page, based on which link is used to get there?

Cheers.

Comment: share your code

Comment: @TamilSelvanC you don't need the code just a better explanation.

Comment: Try to explain it better Asger :)

Comment: One way is to use query strings at the end of your url, and make each link different in the query string. You can then use vanilla js to check the url and apply the required behaviour. Note that this can run into all sorts of issues with when you're changing the DOM, so I wouldn't advise

Comment: in fact, from the wanted behaviour I suspect AJAX may well be how you should be implementing this

Comment: I don't know how to explain it better, but I'll try.

I have a header menu that is positioned absolutely, which I transition in and out of the window with 
function showMenu(){
    menu.style.top = '0%';
    cross.style.top = '2%';
    hamburger.style.top = '-10%';
}
and 
function hideMenu(){
    menu.style.top ='-30%';
    cross.style.top = '-10%';
    hamburger.style.top = '2%';
} Now, if you use the menu, it looks good to use window.onload to remove the menu in the new window. But if you use a link that isn't in the menu to get to the page, it still retracts the menu from open.

Comment: I tried passing a hashtag at the end of my url and then check for that before removing it.
That works, but I'm curious about what kind of trouble I could run into? @Orangesandlemons

Comment: oh, potentially you could end up trying to grab the div to early, or only remove it after it's been rendered etc. I'd use query string values rather than a hash if you are going with that tough- a hash can anchor to an id, while the query parameters are purely for passing data

Answer (score 0):

Pass data to another page as `href` value. Grab this data using PHP and change the behaviour of new page depending upon different values of this data.
Some reference : **[Passing values to another php page using anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071264/passing-values-to-another-php-page-using-anchor-tag)**

Comment: This is not tagged php; in fact it says vanilla JS in the title